# Can dask replace resource managment system?

Tags: dask

Geetings,

Can dask replace a resource management system such as SGE as a scheduler?

I noticed dask can use SGE, yet really what I want to on the long run is replace SGE with something that I can install from conda and looking at dask documentation it seems interesting to try. SGE no longer installs that easily on newer linux systems, so if dask can be used after simple anaconda install it may be better, especially since it runs on windows.

However, looking at documentation, I am still unclear if dask can do the following:

1. Replace qsub command
2. Manages limiting the number of processes per machine
3. Allow dependencies between jobs - I need to wait for a batch of jobs to finish before starting a new batch

I looked at this documentation page that suggests that dask will not fit my needs:
http://dask.pydata.org/en/doc-test-build/distributed-details.html

I was looking at the bottom where it states what dask does not do.

I decided to ask about it in case I was looking at the wrong page in documentation.

Hopefully dask can help.

```
           Jacob
```

Comment: the link to the distributed details is broken - here is the [updated link](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes!

Dask can replace a resource management system such as Sun Grid Engine (SGE) or SLURM in some conditions. I was able to replace SGE with dask for running the MIcro Simualtion Tool (MIST). Here are some insights.

### Limitations:

1. This will not support multiple users using a computer cluster, yet these days with virtualization technology available, the way of running simulations by multiple users on the same cluster can be replaced. Users rarely interact anyway with their jobs, so creating a virtual environment for one user will be ok for most use cases.
2. Complex scheduling with different requirements per job such as specifying jobs that require specific computers are not as easy as defining environment arguments in the qsub command in SGE . Perhaps there is something similar in dask, yet its not as easy to figure out from documentation.
3. Dask does not seem to have nice tools to visualize load and configure such as SGE QMON or SLURM workload manager. Although it can show a nice job graph.

### Advantages:

1. Dask is OS agnostic to some degree. I was able to run the code on Linux and windows while traditional resource management systems are much more OS specific. For example, I am not aware of a SGE version of windows other than discontinues SFU or Cygwin that are not native. SLURM does nt run on Windows
2. Installation of a resource manager is hard, while dask can be easily installed with conda. By the way, make sure that you have the latest version of dask, the version that was released with previous Anaconda 5.0 release for Linux does not work and dask needs an upgrade to work properly on Linux. Yet this is probably fixed in later versions of Anaconda.
3. If you are using Python, you can easily write python code to launch dask the way you want and there are multiple tools to help you setup the computation. Some of them are quite trivial.
4. Dask handles dependencies better than SLURM/SGE due to the graph nature of the tasks. So multiple map/reduce style levels can be easily implemented withint python without resorting to calls to the OS.

In short, I urge developers to consider removing the comment in dask documentation under the title: "What dask.distributed doesn’t do"
http://dask.pydata.org/en/doc-test-build/distributed-details.html

This warning is misleading, dask does require you to wrap your thinking to use it - and it is not suitable for multi user of specialized use. Yet it can easily do fairly complex distributed computations usually submitted as jobs to resource management systems - and it has some advantages. I suggest that developers focus on better comparison showing how things in SGE/SLURM can be transformed to dask and pin point differences.

In a nutshell, I need to do more testing to see how resilient dask is, yet my initial tests are more than satisfactory and I am comfortable writing this answer. Yet I'll be happy to continue discussions if I am missing something here.

I wish I had dask a few years ago - I was looking for such solutions then.

Jacob

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer

No, except in toy situations

#### Long answer

Job schedulers like SGE generally run many programs across a cluster.  These programs typically take many minutes to run and are loosely connected, perhaps by communicating data by files across a file system.

Task schedulers like Dask generally run many functions across programs that are already running on a cluster.  These functions generally take milliseconds to seconds and often communicate lots of data quickly across the network.

In theory by submitting functions that run programs (like with `os.popen`) a task scheduler can mimic a job scheduler if it is already widely deployed across the cluster.  However this is quite rare.  Task schedulers are generally deployed for a short time and then cleaned up.  Job schedulers are around for a lot longer (years) and handle a number of other important issues like user management, quotas, etc..

Comment: Thanks Matt, Yet lets narrow this down. If I want a system capable of burst computation or 5 minute jobs, lets say one year worth of computation time with need for easy deployment for a single  user and computing environment changes like in cloud deployment no special instructions for jobs - jobs are just CPU intensive. And if I am ok with submitting jobs as  os.popen since I have a mechanism to detect failure in the system. In such conditions, will using dask have any advantages such as easy deployment and no need of many dependencies to install other than anaconda?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not able to answer your question.  The right choice of framework depends on many factors.  I hesitate to make any claim about what will or will not work well.  Best of luck!

Comment: So what is the advantage in dask if you already have a job scheduler like SGE running? If dask cannot replace it for tasks such as easy deployment in cloud environment, when should it be used? Can you pin point uses cases where it has a large advantage over SGE? From your answer it seems one should use dask only to augment existing distributed resource management capabilities. Are there counter examples to this?

Comment: Dask has much lower latency, it moves data around directly over the network, it has parallel algorithms for arrays, dataframes, etc.. See more at http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/use-cases.html

Comment: Thanks Matt, you distinguished what is dask better at. You are basically suggesting that dask  is more tied to the data and methods than a resource management system that is more general . Resource management systems such as SGE also have a way to define dependencies between tasks. So parallelism will have to be detailed a bit more to understand the impact there. So let me get back to the original question. If I need to setup a bunch of jobs to run on 3 machines I spin on the cloud. Can I use dask to avoid a complicated installation of a resource management system? Is this another use case?

Comment: Yes you can launch dask on cloud deployments.  See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/setup.html .  I prefer not to comment about relative complexity.  It's not a clear-cut question.  Good luck!

Comment: So Matt, You should consider revising your answer. The answer to the question I asked is YES! Dask can easily replace a resource management system, even with a few advantages if multiple users or specific limits are not needed. I just replaced SGE on my cluster with dask and it seems to work very nice after some tweaking. I suggest that you change dask documentation to clarify where dask is stronger and where a resource management system should be used - I'll try to summarize below.